GUI was not loaded when upgrading from 22.04 to 24,04
I upgraded from 22.o4 to 24.04 when it rebooted it was in a terminal window with no sign of gnome so I did the sudo apt install gnome and got a GUI back but with no toolbar I went into settings to UBUNTU desktop and got the message no ubuntu settings found. "Oops something went wrong (ya think) Please report a bug in launchpad" when I tried to report the problem via launch pad I got a long list of files and dependencies it could not find.How do I fix this? I have a lenovo ideapad flex 5 (16.8)

Try running: sudo apt -f install // sudo dpkg --configure -a // sudo apt update // sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

@DavidDE I don't think that that's the best duplicate question. I'm looking for a question with the same "Oops! Something went wrong!" error message, preferably a question about Ubuntu 24.04. This exact error message is not such a common one in Ubuntu.
